# Python 3 Library for Realtime Midi Communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

Can anyone suggest a good Python 3 Library for sending / receiving reatime MIDI?

Answer (score 1):

Why Python 3? It generally doesn't have many libraries yet. Generally you want to look into high-level C-libraries with Python wrappers. I doubt many of these work under Python 3 at the moment.